# compare url to text in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable called links that stores any URLs that have been visited previously.

I need to match the URLs on the page with the results from the variable. If they match assign the class "visited" to just those links.

So for example if my page has:

```
<a href="link1.html">
<a href="link2.html">
<a href="link3.html">
<a href="link4.html">
<a href="link5.html">
```

and the links variable has:

```
link1.html
link3.html
link4.html
```

In this case like to add the class "visited" to the links that are stored in the variable link1.html, link3.html and link4.html in this case. There are loads of links with all sorts of text. These ones are just for a simple example.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rightbox li a').each(

    function(intIndex){
        var links = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(links);
        $.ajax({
            url: links,
            type:'HEAD',
            error: function() { },
            success: function() {
                var visited = (links)
                $("#visitedLinkContainer").append(visited);

                $(this).attr('href').addClass("visited");`
                // I tried this but it adds visited to everylink which I knew would, but I don't know what to put here`
            }
        });                     
    });
});
```

This is for a personal project at home. I'm using local storage at the moment, but I'd prefer to do it this way if possible.

Thank you for any help received

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  $('#rightbox li a[href="' + link + '"]').addClass('visited');
});
```

The jQuery selector `[<attribute>="<value>"]` selects elements that their `<attribute>` equals to `<value>`.

Comment: Where you want to mark the visited links with the class `visited`. I think it's in you ajax success function.

Comment: I tried your answer, but I got `links.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Your `links` variable isn't an rray of URLs, is a single variable. You should change your code so: `var links = []; $('#rightbox li a').each(function(intIndex) { links.push($(this).attr('href')); });`.

Comment: Thank you very much, still so much to learn. It works great now.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwMbgp

**html**

```
<a href="#1">Link1</a>
<a href="#2">Link2</a>
<a href="#3">Link3</a>
<a href="#4">Link4</a>
<a href="#5">Link5</a>
<a href="#2">Link2</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.visited {
  color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Faking that you already entered the first 2 links
var visited = ['#1', '#2'];

// when clicking it adds the class visited right away
  $( "a" ).click(function() {
    visited.push($(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).addClass( "visited" );
  });

// loop trough the visited url and find the corresponding a tags that all have the urls inside the visited variable
  $.each(visited, function( index, value ) {
    // this gets all links with that same value, if you don't want this you need to store something unique of the a tag or the entire element inside the var visited 
    var allLinks = $('a[href^="' + value + '"]');
    $.each(allLinks, function() {
       $(this).addClass( "visited" )
    })
    // this allert shows you what index and value are
    alert( index + ": " + value );
  });

});
```

Hope this helped somehow

Answer (score 0):

convert this line [`var links = $(this).attr('href');`], to this:

```
var LINK = $(this), 
    links = LINK.attr('href');
```

now, after line `$("#visitedLinkContainer").append(visited);` put here instead of yours code:

```
LINK.addClass("visited");
```

or try this:

```
$("#rightbox [href='"+links+"']").addClass("visited");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<arrayOfLinksAlreadyVisited.length;i++) {
    $("#rightbox li a").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href") == arrayOfLinksAlreadyVisited[i])) {
            $(this).addClass("visited");
        }    
        //Match the href with  arrayOfLinksAlreadyVisited[i]
        //if true then addClass visited to this anchor tag via 
        //keyword this
        // else do nothing  
    });   
}
```

I hope the above logic will work for you.